# VB6 how to make an EXE wait for events to complete in DLL

Tags: events, vb6

[image: EXE to DLL Flow Image]

**INTRO**

I have a DLL that uses Events to interact with a hardware device. In summary, I am wanting to have the main EXE app to wait at various points while the hardware interface DLL does its thing with the hardware, and then passes results back to the main call app, via another DLL 
(see image above)

**STRUCTURE of MODULES**

The EXE ;
is just a simple test app that calls various functions in the Calling DLL, which in turn calls functions in the Operating DLL. 
The last Device DLL is just the normal hardware distribution driver type DLL from the manufacturer.

The Calling DLL ; 
is a generic dll that does various processing for my apps including dynamically loading various hardware Operating DLL's as required, passing back common info translated from various and more specific Operating DLL's. It is kind of like a funnel I guess.

Operating DLL ; 
exists per hardware device connected to the PC. It could be for any device such as a webcam, scanner and so on. These DLL's were written to talk to the generic Calling DLL at one end, and the manufacturers DLL at the other end.

**SUMMARY**

I am able to compile the Operating DLL into an EXE for testing. In this state it has a Form with a few buttons. Those buttons are "Open" "Close" "Scan1" "Scan2"
These same "buttons" are called via the Calling DLL when the Operating DLL is compiled as a DLL. Hope that makes sense. 
So in other words, I can test the Operating DLL in native mode as an EXE - and it runs fine, and I can compile it as a DLL to be consumed by the Calling DLL.

Scan1 and Scan2 functions use Event handling.

So, the Operating DLL as an EXE , I can Open and Connect to the device via the device dll using internal calls from with Operating DLL. Work fine, events work, app steps through fine. This is mainly due I guess to the structure of the Form layout in the Operating DLL, it just what it has to per button. It still uses Events internally but externally (at the Form level) it just has to do that cycle per the button I select being Scan1 or Scan2.

**PROBLEM**

The issue is this, when the Operating DLL is compiled as just that, a DLL, the instructions are issues by the Calling DLL which is one level up. The Calling DLL has a code pathway and in there is a Call to the Operating DLL to tell it to Scan1. 
That's fine, however, the Calling DLL then just continues on its way and does not wait for the Operating DLL to complete and return the required Data. 
Therefore the Calling DLL is failing. It is just rushing through and does not receive any data back.

**CODE**

**This is the "Calling DLL - it consumes the Operating DLL"**

```
** This function is used to call the Operating DLL and run the Events
**
Private Function IScanDevice_Scan1(Collections As Template, ByVal ScanPurpose As ScanPurposes, ByVal ScanTimeout As Integer, Region As ScanRegion) As Scan_ResultCodes

'* call the Operating DLL processes which use Events 
'*
ScanCollected = Scan1(Collections, ScanPurpose, mScanTimeout, mRegion)


'* The following should only execute after all Operating DLL stuff completes
'*        
   MsgBox ("Scan1 Call for Operating DLL completed)
   Call printResults
.
.
End Function
```

**This is the "Operating DLL - also can be compiled as an EXE for testing"**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents obj As OPOSBiometrics    

''
' This implements the IScanDevice interface.

Implements IScanDevice

.
.

** Used by the Calling DLL    
Public Function IScanDevice_Scan1(Collections As BBScan.Template, ByVal ScanPurpose As BBScan.ScanPurposes, ByVal ScanTimeout As Integer, Region As BBScan.ScanRegion) As BBScan.Scan_ResultCodes
  .
  RC = TestDemo.DoBeginCapture
  .
  .

** This is called from the Form internally when in EXE mode
** and called from the Calling DLL via IScanDevice_Scan1 above
Public Function DoBeginCapture() As RC_ResultCodes
.
  obj.DataEventEnabled = True
  dataEvent = dEvent.BeginCapture
. 
.
Exit Function


'**Event Processing**    
Public Sub obj_DataEvent(ByVal Status As Long)

On Error GoTo Error_DataEvent

Select Case dataEvent

   Case dEvent.Identify
         dataEvent = dEvent.None

   Case dEvent.BeginVerify
CoreScan = obj.BIR
 ret = obj.EndCapture()
If ret = OposSuccess Then
            .
Else
.
End If

            obj.DataEventEnabled = True
dataEvent = dEvent.None

    Case dEvent.Register

            ret = obj.EndCapture()
         If ret = OposSuccess Then
.
         Else
.
         End If

obj.DataEventEnabled = True

         dataEvent = dEvent.None

End Select
.
.
End Sub
```

So in summary the Calling DLL displays the MsgBox and tries to run the printReport function without the  Operating DLL  IScanDevice_Scan1  function completing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me where / when you return from the initial call to `_Scan1`. If, as seems likely, you return immediately after invoking `BeginCapture` then you are returning control to the caller before any internal processing or events occur in the callee, and program flow continues from there.

If it's important that processing in the calling DLL be suspended until something happens in the called DLL, you must either keep the locus of control in the called DLL, or wait in the calling DLL for some event to be signaled from the caller.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Correct, the DLL just does it's processing which is primarily hardware related input interfacing, and then it exits with a return of some info to the Calling DLL. 

Agree with you however apart from a hard Wait in Seconds n the Processing DLL which I would like to avoid, I cannot see a way of holding focus on the DLL while the Events process. Is there an approach to this ?

Comment: @GarthJones You can do an indefinite wait in the caller, after the called DLL returns, until the called DLL raises an event or other signal. This assumes there's a way to know when all the processing is complete. If you can't accomplish this with a VB event, then register an event with the system using `CreateEvent`, call `WaitForSingleEvent` in the caller, and signal the event in the callee.